# Oracle FORALL Update Exception

Tags: oracle, plsql, forall

I'm using a FORALL Statement in order to update a lot of registers from a table, what I need to do is catch an exception when the update "fails" because  the department number XXX does not exist.

```
FORALL x IN TABLE_DEPTO_DESCRIPTION.First .. TABLE_DEPTO_DESCRIPTION.Last SAVE EXCEPTIONS
    UPDATE DEPARTMENTS SET
      DESCRIPTION = TABLE_DEPTO_DESCRIPTION(x).DESCRIPTION
    WHERE DPTO_NUMBER =TABLE_DEPTO_DESCRIPTION(x).id;
```

Answer (score 1):

An update statement that updates no rows is not an error so there is no exception to catch.  You could inspect the `sql%bulk_rowcount` collection after the `FORALL` to identify updates that modified 0 rows of data

```
FORALL ...

FOR i IN 1 .. SQL%BULK_ROWCOUNT.count
LOOP
  IF( sql%bulk_rowcount(i) = 0 )
  THEN
    -- TABLE_DEPTO_DESCRIPTION(i).id updated 0 rows.
    -- Do something as a result
  END IF;
END LOOP;
```